# Proof of Uniqueness of Numbers on the Main Diagonal in a Symmetrical 15x15 Grid

Tags: combinatorics

This question is from the book "Mathematical Circles" by Moscow.

> In each cell of a $15 \times 15$ grid, one of the numbers $1, 2, 3, \ldots, 15$ is written. Cells that are symmetrical with respect to one
> of the main diagonals contain the same numbers, and no row or column
> contains two copies of the same number. Show that all the numbers on
> this main diagonal are different.

**Attempt:**

Basically, we will have 14 symmetrical positions with respect to the diagonal, divided into pairs. Each pair consists of different numbers among other pairs: $(1, 1)$, $(2, 2)$, and so on... Since there will be at least one number without a corresponding pair, this number will be its symmetrical counterpart, therefore, it will be on the diagonal. From this, how can I explain that the main diagonal will have different numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient to show that every integer from $1$ to $15$ must appear on the main diagonal at least once.

**Proof**: Let $b$ be some integer from $1$ to $15$. Suppose that

- the integer $b$ appears on the main diagonal $b_{\text{diag}}$ times,
- the integer $b$ appears on the cells above the main diagonal $b_{\text{above}}$ times,
- the integer $b$ appears on the cells below the main diagonal $b_{\text{below}}$ times.

We know that $$b_{\text{above}} = b_{\text{below}}$$ due to the symmetry of the grid. Moreover, we also know that $$b_{\text{diag}} + b_{\text{above}} + b_{\text{below}} = 15$$ because every number appears exactly once on every row (and every column) and there are exactly $15$ rows (and columns).

As a result, $$b_{\text{diag}} = 15 - b_{\text{above}} - b_{\text{below}} = 15 - 2b_{\text{below}}.$$ Consequently, $b_{\text{diag}}$ must be odd, and hence, $b_{\text{diag}} \neq 0$. In other words, the integer $b$ must appear at least once on the main diagonal.